# Suppress Incorrect error message

Tags: 7, status-messages

My website is using Drupal 7, secure login, and r4032login. I get this message when I log into a page that was redirected to the login page when access was denied:

> You are accessing  using an unencrypted connection. For your security,  only supports account logins using a secure protocol such as HTTPS. You can switch to HTTPS by trying to view this page again after changing the URL in your browser's location bar to begin with "https" instead of "http". Please contact  for help if this error continues.

This is untrue, as every time this message appears the sites url is https://www.mysite.com
What can I do about his message? What is the underlying cause? How can I suppress this if it can't be solved?

Update: This is not being caused by r4032login or secure login. I disabled and unistalled these module, and after logging in, the message is still displayed.

Comment: If you refresh the page when you get the message is it still there? If not, that message is probably left over in the session from the page that redirects back to login. I would suspect whatever module you're using to do that (maybe r4032login?)

Comment: are you running the drupal6 ldap_integration module? https://www.drupal.org/node/2012348

Comment: @Clive you might be right there. If you refresh then the message goes away. Thanks for helping me understand at what point in the process the message is being generated.

Comment: @tenken This is a drupal 7 site, and has no previous drupal 6 site, so no I am not running ldap_integration module. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this error message was being created when clicking on a link that had http selected as its protocol.